# Biztalk WCF service publishing wizard

Tags: wcf, biztalk

I have exposed a schema as a WCFService.

But when I browse the .svc file, it is taking me to the WSDL file. Any one knows the reason.

[image]

web.config file:

```
 <behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehaviorConfiguration">
      <serviceDebug httpHelpPageEnabled="true" httpsHelpPageEnabled="false" includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
      <serviceMetadata  httpsGetEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <!--<endpointBehaviors><behavior name="sharedSecretClientCredentials"><transportClientEndpointBehavior><tokenProvider><sharedSecret issuerName="owner" issuerSecret="ABCD" /><sharedAccessSignature keyName="RootManageSharedAccessKey" key="ABCD" /></tokenProvider></transportClientEndpointBehavior><serviceRegistrySettings discoveryMode="Public" /><btsWsdlExporter btsServiceDescriptionLocation="ServiceDescription.xml" debug="false" isRelay="false" /></behavior><behavior name="sharedSecretClientCredentialsMex"><transportClientEndpointBehavior><tokenProvider><sharedSecret issuerName="owner" issuerSecret="ABCD" /><sharedAccessSignature keyName="RootManageSharedAccessKey" key="ABCD" /></tokenProvider></transportClientEndpointBehavior><serviceRegistrySettings discoveryMode="Public" /></behavior></endpointBehaviors>-->
</behaviors>
<services>
  <!-- Note: the service name must match the configuration name for the service implementation. -->
  <service name="Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.BizTalkServiceInstance" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviorConfiguration">
    <!--<endpoint name="HttpMexEndpoint" address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="IMetadataExchange" />-->
    <endpoint name="HttpsMexEndpoint" address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <!--<endpoint name="RelayEndpoint" address="sb://test01.servicebus.windows.net/EchoServiceNetTcp/" binding="netTcpRelayBinding" bindingNamespace="http://tempuri.org/" bindingConfiguration="RelayEndpointConfig" behaviorConfiguration="sharedSecretClientCredentials" contract="Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.ITwoWayAsyncVoid" />-->
    <!--<endpoint name="MexEndpoint" address="https://test01.servicebus.windows.net/EchoServiceNetTcp/Mex" binding="ws2007HttpRelayBinding" bindingNamespace="http://tempuri.org/" bindingConfiguration="RelayEndpointConfigMex" behaviorConfiguration="sharedSecretClientCredentialsMex" contract="IMetadataExchange" />-->
  </service>
</services>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the httpsHelpPageEnabled property to true since you're trying to access that page on the HTTPS protocol.